# Consolidating Multiple WordPress Multisites into One

Tags: wordpress

I did some research but couldn't find any good literature on how to consolidate multiple instances of WordPress Multisite into one instance. To be clear, I have three multisites and want to merge them into one; is there a good/easy way to do this other than exporting/importing all of the sites manually?

Comment: Maybe carefully merging their databases. [Some info](http://halfelf.org/2012/moving-wordpress-multisite/) about it. Search in Mika's archives, she's a MS expert, lots of good stuff there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment- this post definitely helped me out.  I found out that you need to reorder the DB table numbers, and then edit the wp_blogs table and everything works fine once you change the nameservers for the domain.  Now the problem is that there's no good way to automate this so I unfortunately have to do this manually for a lot of domains.

Comment: It'll be nice if you post a summary of what you're doing as an Answer bellow. I used BackupBuddy, but gradually they've been removing support/features for MS handling. It was the best tool I knew of and many times I had to modify the DB myself between exports/imports.

Comment: Sorry about that- I'll do that now :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one answer that I found- it's not fast but it definitely works.

I will refer to **first MS** as the multisite that you want to remove a site from and **second MS** as the multisite that you want to add this site to.

**Step 1**

In phpmyadmin or similar for **first MS**, export the tables relevant to the site that you're taking.  It'll probably look something like:

- wp_7_commentmeta
- wp_7_comments
- wp_7_links
- wp_7_options
- wp_7_postmeta
- wp_7_posts
- wp_7_terms
- wp_7_term_relationships

I'm going to call the **site number** the number corresponding to the middle number in the DB tables.  In this case, the **site number** is 7.

**Step 2**

Go to phpmyadmin for **second MS** and see what the largest DB site number is.

**Step 3**

In a code editor do a find replace for your current site number and replace it with a site number that is **one larger than the biggest site number in the second MS** DB.  For instance, if the largest site number in **second MS** was 460 using the example above I would do a find/replace for "wp_7_" and replace it with "wp_461_".

**Step 4**

Once you've done this, import the updated .sql file into the **second MS** DB.

**Step 5**

Enter the options table for the site you just imported (now wp_461_options) and make sure that the "siteurl" and "home" options correspond to the new site.

**Step 6**

Go to the wp_blogs table in the DB and insert new information for the site you just added. Be sure that the "blog_id" corresponds to the site number you just created (in my example I would make sure that "blog_id" was 461).

**Step 7**

You should now be able to safely change the nameservers on your domain to the **second MS** and it should work.

If anyone knows of a way to automate this, or to make it easier to do in bulk that would be phenominal. Otherwise this way will work, albeit slowly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of 3rd party tools which can make the process a whole lot simpler - [BackupBuddy for example](http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/) can deal with exporting Multisite sites and importing them to existing installs.

I've used this successfully to move a few sites around, but success rates can often depend on how many user accounts are involved as Multisite maps all accounts onto a single table of accounts.

IMHO, unless there's a very good reason to consolidate them, it can often be a whole lot easier to keep the installations separate.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go check BackupBuddy now. I completely agree about consolidating being a last option but unfortunately we do have to do it.